# Asp.net / Javascript remove value of input field when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

right now I have a javascript that disables from inputs fields for me. And this is the script that is doing that.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#check').click(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked') === true){
            $('#startTime').prop("disabled","disabled");
            $('#endTime').prop("disabled","disabled");
            $('#breakTime').prop("disabled","disabled");
            $('#workedHours').prop("disabled","disabled");
            $('#addMoreProjects').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#projectName').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#description_1').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#hours_1').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        else {
            $('#startTime').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#endTime').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#breakTime').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#workedHours').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#addMoreProjects').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#projectName').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#description_1').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#hours_1').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

But by default my Input fields has values in them, and when I disble the input fields the values are still there. What I would like to do is when I check the textbox, it will disable the Input field, and remove the value that is inside the box. And when I uncheck it I want that value to be added back.

This is my view:

```
<div class="portlet-body form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-5">Ingen tid att rapportera</label>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.NoTimeToReport, new { @id = "check" })
    </div>
    @if (Model.ReportId.HasValue)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Redigera datum:</label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.TextBox("date", Model.Date.ToShortDateString(), new {@class = "form-control", @readonly = "true"})
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Start tid:</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBox("startTime", Model.Times.StartTime, new {@class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Slut tid:</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBox("endTime", Model.Times.EndTime, new {@class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Rast Längd:</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBox("breakTime", Model.Times.BreakTime, new {@class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Tid jobbad:</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBox("workedHours", Model.Times.WorkedHours, new {@class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24"})
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
var startTime = $('#startTime');
var endTime = $('#endTime')
var breakTime = $('#breakTime');
var workedHours = $('#workedHours');
var addMoreProjects = $('#addMoreProjects');
var projectName = $('#projectName');
var description_1 = $('#description_1');
var hours_1 = $('#hours_1');

if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
    startTime.attr('disabled', 'disabled').attr('data-value', startTime.val()).val('');
                endTime.attr('disabled', 'disabled').attr('data-value', endTime.val()).val('');
                breakTime.attr('disabled', 'disabled').attr('data-value', breakTime.val()).val('');
                workedHours.attr('disabled', 'disabled').attr('data-value', workedHours.val()).val('');
                addMoreProjects.attr('disabled', 'disabled').attr('data-value', addMoreProjects.val()).val('');
                projectName.attr('disabled', 'disabled').attr('data-value', projectName.val()).val('');
                hours_1.attr('disabled', 'disabled').attr('data-value', hours_1.val()).val('');
                description_1.attr('disabled', 'disabled').attr('data-value', description_1.val()).val('');
}
else {   
  startTime.removeAttr('disabled').val(startTime.attr('data-value'));
  endTime.removeAttr('disabled').val(endTime.attr('data-value'));
  breakTime.removeAttr('disabled').val(breakTime.attr('data-value'));
  workedHours.removeAttr('disabled').val(workedHours.attr('data-value'));
 addMoreProjects.removeAttr('disabled').val(addMoreProjects.attr('data-value'));
 projectName.removeAttr('disabled').val(projectName.attr('data-value'));
 hours_1.removeAttr('disabled').val(hours_1.attr('data-value'));
 description_1.removeAttr('disabled').val(description_1.attr('data-value'));
}
```

Comment: That, broke everything.

Comment: now it does disable the checkboxes like before, but it dosen't remove the value the input field holds.

Comment: it is a checkbox any spefic reason why change would be better? Or just best practice ?

Comment: well if user change checkbox from keyboard the click event will not fire so its better to use change and also a best practice

Comment: This will not work if a user is changing the text and then is clicking the checkbox.

Comment: @avi it why it will not work can you expalin i don't think so?

Comment: @MKA If you have for example at start the text "hello" and you modify it in "no hello", after checking and unchecking the checkbox...you will have the "hello" text again... not the text you had before checking the checkbox.

Comment: @avi really please see the behaviour of the code m getting value evry time and set to data attribut or try it yourself before argu..

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you should do some extra javascript logic.You could keep your data hidden in some `data-value` attribute. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cz56dppo/) you have an example for a single element.

The trick to preserve the logic for the modified text is to add a change event for each of your textboxes like this:

```
$( "#someTextbox" ).change(function() {
  $("#someTextbox").attr('data-value', $(this).val());
});
```

In order to use this in your situation try to edit the render of textbox similar to (basically i have added the data_value for your textbox, note that you need to wirte it with "_", mvc will take care of the correct formatting):

```
 @Html.TextBox("startTime", Model.Times.StartTime, new {@class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24", data_value = Model.Times.StartTime.ToString()})
```

Comment: It's working great on the fiddle, thanks for the fast reply. Though I am facing one issue. It is removing the current value and disables the input field, but this. this         $("#startTime").change(function() {
            $("#startTime").attr('data-value', $(this).val());
        });´´ Dosen't seem to put back the old value.

Comment: i have updated my answer to show you how you should add the data-value for your control

Comment: right, that is my bad I saw that data-value in the fiddle now.

Answer (score 0):

As you are storing you value in "startTime" textbox, what you can do is just use hiddenfield and store the same value in it and then you can change your code like below.

In Else Part:

```
$('#startTime').val('');
$('#startTime').removeAttr('disabled');
```

In If Part:

```
$('#startTime').val($('#your date time hidden field').val());
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I did try something simular to this what would happend when I check the checkbox the input field will get disabled, and when I uncheck it it will remove the value and never add it back.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple example in `javascript` :

```js
function chk(ele) {
    var n1=document.getElementById('txtName');
    var n2=document.getElementById('txtName2');
    if(ele.checked) {
        n1.disabled=false;n2.disabled=false;
        n1.value=n1.getAttribute('data-value');
        n2.value=n2.getAttribute('data-value');
        n1.focus();
    } else {
        n1.setAttribute('data-value',n1.value);
        n2.setAttribute('data-value',n2.value);
        n1.value='';n2.value='';
        n1.disabled=true;n2.disabled=true;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="chk(this);" checked />Check me
<br><br>
First name : <input type="text" id="txtName" value="" data-value="" />
<br><br>
Last name : <input type="text" id="txtName2" value="" data-value="" />
```